# Rails: Calling virtualenv for Python from within a Rails app

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, virtualenv

I'm trying to run a Python script from within my Rails app. Before calling the Python script, I need to start up its `virtualenv`, so I tried doing this:

```
result = %x(
           cd /path/to/python/script/;
           source venv/bin/activate;
           python myscript.py
           )
```

I get the error message `source not found`, apparently indicating that the virtual environment is not getting successfully set up.

When I type these commands directly in bash, it works fine. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your default shell is not `bash`, but `sh`, which does not have command `source`. You can make it run in `bash` explicitly this way:

```
%x(/bin/bash -c '
  cd /path/to/python/script/;
  source venv/bin/activate;
  python myscript.py
  ')
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried it and the error message is gone .. that's not the whole story though. I'm deploying this to Dokku, and `virtualenv` doesn't seem to be installed by default. Outside the scope of this question though, but thanks anyway!